# Hive query to quickly find table size (number of rows)

Tags: hadoop, hive

Is there a Hive query to quickly find table size (i.e. number of rows) without launching a time-consuming MapReduce job? (Which is why I want to avoid `COUNT(*)`.)

I tried `DESCRIBE EXTENDED`, but that yielded `numRows=0` which is obviously not correct.

(Apologies for the newb question. I tried Googling and searching the apache.org documentation without success.)

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45304801/7043815)!!! hope it helps :)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

tblproperties will give the size of the table and can be used to grab just that value if needed.

```
-- gives all properties
show tblproperties yourTableName

-- show just the raw data size
show tblproperties yourTableName("rawDataSize")
```

Comment: Apparently the given command only works when these properties are available to the column, which is not there by default.

Comment: Yes the output is bytes. Also, this only works for non-partitioned tables which have had stats run on them.

Answer (score 31):

Here is the quick command

```
ANALYZE TABLE tablename [PARTITION(partcol1[=val1], partcol2[=val2], ...)] COMPUTE STATISTICS [noscan];
```

For Example,If table is partitioned

```
 hive> ANALYZE TABLE ops_bc_log PARTITION(day) COMPUTE STATISTICS noscan;
```

output is

> Partition logdata.ops_bc_log{day=20140523} stats: [numFiles=37,
>   numRows=26095186, totalSize=654249957, rawDataSize=58080809507]
>
> Partition logdata.ops_bc_log{day=20140521} stats: [numFiles=30,
>   numRows=21363807, totalSize=564014889, rawDataSize=47556570705]
>
> Partition logdata.ops_bc_log{day=20140524} stats: [numFiles=35,
>   numRows=25210367, totalSize=631424507, rawDataSize=56083164109]
>
> Partition logdata.ops_bc_log{day=20140522} stats: [numFiles=37,
>   numRows=26295075, totalSize=657113440, rawDataSize=58496087068]

Comment: Note, per the [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/StatsDev) the "noscan" parameter will prevent a scan the files to get a correct count of the number of rows. You will get total size though. In your case, it might have worked because you were gathering stats by config.

Comment: @DanielLangdon are the units of rawDataSize bytes, blocks or something else?

Comment: bytes @DanielLangdon

Comment: Sorry guys, I moved positions and companies a while ago and do not remember much details.

Answer (score 11):

How about using :

```
    hdfs dfs -du -s -h /path/to/table/name
```

Comment: I tried this and it says 12.8 G does it stand for 12.8 GB?

Comment: @Constantine1991 yes !

Answer (score 1):

solution, though not quick
if the table is partitioned, we can count the number of partitions and count(number of rows) in each partition.
For example:, if partition by date (mm-dd-yyyy)

```
select partition_date, count(*) from <table_name> where <partion_column_name> >= '05-14-2018' group by <partion_column_name>
```

Answer (score -2):

Use parquet format to store data of your external/internal table. Then you will get quicker results.

Answer (score -6):

It is a good question. the count(*) will take much time for finding the result. But unfortunately, count(*) is the only way to do.

There is an alternative way(can't say alternate but better latency than above case) :

Set the property

**set hive.exec.mode.local.auto=true;**

and run the same command ( `select count(*) from tbl` ) which gives better latency than prior.

Comment: There are indeed other ways. See other answer below.