# Get total size of HIVE partitioned table

Tags: hadoop, hive

We have HDP 2.6 cluster with HIVE 2.0.We have created clustered partitioned internal table in HIVE. We need to know size of total table in HIVE.

We already have issued ANALYZE command against same.

```
ANALYZE TABLE A_ITT_ITEM_SALES COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR COLUMNS;
```

When we try to check size -

```
describe extended a_itt_item_sales
```

In Detailed Table infromation I get -

```
...parameters:{}, skewedInfo:SkewedInfo(skewedColNames:[], skewedColValues:[], skewedColValueLocationMaps:{}), storedAsSubDirectories:false), partitionKeys:[FieldSchema(name:trans_date, type:date, comment:null)], parameters:{transient_lastDdlTime=1529059590, last_modified_time=1529059590, last_modified_by=admin, serialization.null.format=}, viewOriginalText:null, viewExpandedText:null, tableType:MANAGED_TABLE)...
```

How do we get total size of table when it is clustered partitioned/compressed?

Comment: Checkout the similar question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208574/hive-query-to-quickly-find-table-size-number-of-rows

Answer (score 0):

`hdfs dfs -du -s -h /users/hive/warehouse/A_ITT_ITEM_SALES`

(adapt the HDFS path to your deployment settings)